# TypeScript compiler complains about nulls when using isNull

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

When I have `strictNullChecks: true` in tsconfig.json and use `isNull` for null checks, the compiler throws the error `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'`. `isNull` gets rid of the error in VsCode, but the compiler still complains when I'm trying to build and run my Angular app. If I use `=== null` for null checks, no error.

Is there a way to tell the compiler to respect `isNull` as a valid null check?

```
import { isNull } from "util"; // from @types/node
    ...

    public run() {
        this.printS("hello");
        this.printS(null);
    }

    public printS(s: string | null) {
        if (isNull(s)) {
            console.log("s is null");
            return;
        }
        console.log("s is not null: ", s.toString()); // error on this line
    }
```

```
"typescript": "~3.2.2"
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
```

Comment: Weird I'm not getting the error at the moment. Why do you want to use `isNull` in the first place? It's deprecated and suggests using `value === null`

Comment: You could try wrapping that line in an else statement to force evaluation of `isNull`. As @IoannisPotouridis says, it is actually deprecated so you should consider using `value === null` instead

Answer (score 0):

isNull is deprecated since node v4.

```js
    /** @deprecated since v4.0.0 - use `value === null` instead. */
    function isNull(object: any): object is null;
```

simply use `s === null`. That's enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, isNull() function is deprecated but if you already have used isNull() function many times in your code and if you don't want to change them everywhere, you can just make your own function named isNull() and use that function.

```
function isNull(object:any){
           if(object === null){
               return true 
               }
           else {
               return false
               }
           }
```